GoogleTestでグローバル変数を設定してテストしたい
GoogleTestのグローバル変数の設定方法について教えてください。
GoogleTestを使い分岐網羅の確認をしているのですが、グローバル変数が条件にある分岐で、事前に設定した値の意図した分岐に入らず困っています。
GoogleTestの超入門やクックブック、チートシートを見てみましたが当てはまりそうな内容がなく、
また「GoogleTest global variable」で検索してもそれらしき内容が見当たりませんでした。
GoogleTestでのグローバル変数の扱い方についてきちんと理解していない箇所もあるかもしれませんが、解決方法があれば教えていただきたいです。
環境:
Ubuntu 20.04
不足点等あれば補足します。
(追記:GlobalStの定義位置を追加しました)
(test.cpp)
#include "target.cpp"

TEST(TargetTest, GlobalCheck)
{
    GlobalSt.mem = THRESHOLD_MAX + 1;
    target_func();

    EXPECT_EQ(THRESHOLD_MAX, GlobalSt.mem);
    // memが0でFAILしていた

(target.cpp)
#include "TestHeader.h"
void target_func(void)
{
    int val;
    if (GlobalSt.mem <= THRESHOLD_MAX)
    {
        val = GlobalSt.mem;
        // else節に誘導したいが分岐直前にprintfで中身を見るとmemが0になっていた
    }
    else
    {
        val = THRESHOLD_MAX;
        // else節に入らない
    }
    (後略)
}

(TypeDefinition.h)
typedef struct {
    int mem;
    int mem_2;
} TestSt;

(TestVariable.h)
static TestSt GlobalSt;

(TestHeader.h)
extern "C" {
#include "TypeDefinition.h"
#include "TestVariable.h"
}


GlobalSt.mem をどこでどうやって宣言・定義していますか?

質問内容にGlobalStの定義位置を追記しました。

// TestVariable.h
static TestSt GlobalSt;

ヘッダで static の変数を定義するのは、ほとんどのケースで間違いです。
target.cpp からも test.cpp からも TestVariable.h をインクルードしているのだと思いますが、それぞれの翻訳単位用に独立した GlobalSt 変数が2つ作られます。
ヘッダでは extern TestSt GlobalSt; としておき、TestVariable.c か何かで実体を定義しましょう。

改めて見直したところ、対象コード内で見落としがあったためそれに対応したテストコードで実施したら解決しました。ただ、int32_tさんの言う通りで実体が.cに無いのもおかしいためそちらも修正いたしました。ありがとうございました！

解決済みですが、よりよい対応方法があります。
C++17でインライン変数という機能強化がされています。
// TestVariable.h
inline TestSt GlobalSt;

で完結し、別の場所で実体を定義不要になります。
